# Execute a for loop in parallel instead of sequential order when underlying method returns void

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, guava, runnable

I have a class in which my `add` method is being called by multiple threads to populate `clientidToTimestampHolder` LinkedBlockingQueue. And then in the same below class, I start a background thread which runs every 30 milliseconds and calls a `processData()` method which drains `clientidToTimestampHolder` to List of Map and then I iterate that List to send data to different service by calling appropriate method.

I can get same userid many times with different timestamp so that is why I am using LinkedBlockingQueue with map.

```
public class Handler {
  private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors
      .newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
  private final LinkedBlockingQueue<Map.Entry<String, Long>> clientidToTimestampHolder =
      new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

  private static class Holder {
    private static final Handler INSTANCE = new Handler();
  }

  public static Handler getInstance() {
    return Holder.INSTANCE;
  }

  private Handler() {
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        processData();
      }
    }, 0, 30, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  }

  // called by multiple threads to populate clientidToTimestampHolder map
  public void add(final String clientid, final Long timestamp) {
    clientidToTimestampHolder.offer(Maps.immutableEntry(clientid, timestamp));
  }

  // called by single background thread every 30 milliseconds
  public void processData() {
    final List<Map.Entry<String, Long>> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    clientidToTimestampHolder.drainTo(entries);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : entries) {
      String clientid = entry.getKey();
      long timestamp = entry.getValue();
      boolean isUpdated = isUpdatedClient(clientid, timestamp);
      if (!isUpdated) {
        updateClient(String.valueOf(clientid));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is my above code thread safe and there is no race condition? Since `add` method will be called from multiple threads and then I have a single background thread which runs every 30 milliseconds to calls `processData()` method which extracts data from `clientidToTimestampHolder` LinkedBlockingQueue.

Because right now it looks like under heavy load, my `processData()` method might be missing few entries which got added through `add` method. I added few logs in my `add` method which printed out the `clientid` but somehow that same `clientid` didn't got printed out in the logs I added in `isUpdatedClient` method so making it suspicious to me somehow.

I am working with Java 7.

Comment: if you want to check exception in the called method or if you expect return result,then use callable,else you can use runnable

Comment: @MohanaPriyan there is no return result, and submit(Runnable) checks exception the same way as submit(Callable). So submit(Runnable) is OK.

Answer (score 0):

`submit(Runnable)` would work the same way as  `submit(Callable)` you use now. 
There are also aspects which could kill all advantages of parallel execution.

First, you use `newCachedThreadPool`. This means, that when all pool threads are busy, a new pool thread is created. Thread creation is an expensive operation, and consumes a lot of memory. You should restrict the number of threads in the pool. If your tasks are purely computational, use number of available processors. If tasks access a database, use max number of simultaneous connections the database can handle.

Second, if your tasks (which include `isUpdatedClient()` and `updateClient`) are too small, then overhead of task creation and submission can be too high. In this case I'd create tasks which contain several entries, and process them in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in the following way:

1. Create a Class which incapsulates some data which you need to process. And the logic of processing. In this case it may be like a `ClientProcessor` class with `Client` field
2. I don't see why you need some 3rd party executor implementations, so I'll use Java Executors. However, with another implementations approach will be similar.
3. Create needed amount of ClientProcessor objects by reading them from source / using some factory -> and submit these tasks to the executor.

Below is a simple example:

```
public class Client {
    private String id;
    private String timeStamp;

    public Client(String id, String timeStamp) {
        this.id = id;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }
}
```

ClientProcessor:

```
public class ClientProcessor implements Runnable{

    private Client client;

    public ClientProcessor(Client client) {
        super();
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // do anything needed with the Client field
        System.out.println(client);
    }
}
```

Main

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {
    public Main() throws InterruptedException {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            executor.submit(new ClientProcessor(new Client("id" + i, "timestamp_" + i)));
        }

        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One completely different approach: use Java8 streams.

Meaning: first rework your code to start with:

```
entries.stream(). ...
```

because then, turning it into "parallel" *might* only need to replace it with

```
entries.parallelStream(). ...
```

I am not too much into streams yet; but there are good example sites, like this [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-filter-a-map-examples/).